# Grid offset by one

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Ok, so I've been trying to get a grid to work on my canvas. Here's what I've got:

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/kyozm/pen/NbRmBK?editors=0010)

```
for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        var pix = new Pixel(i, j);
        grid.push(pix);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that on the grid array, the pixel on index 0 is actually the 2nd one and the last is the 1st. I want to change that but I can't see what the problem in the code is.

Comment: Maybe using `new Pixel(j, i);` instead of `new Pixel(i, j);`?

Comment: no, that will cause the the grid to rotate 90º

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your `Pixel#draw()` function:

```
this.draw = function () {
    rect(this.x, this.y, l, l);
    fill(0);
    stroke(20);
    if (this.on)
        fill(255);
}
```

Read this code line by line and really think about exactly what it's doing. Step through it with a piece of paper and a pencil to understand exactly what's going on.

Notice that you're calling the `rect()` function **first**, and then you're setting the fill and stroke.

This will cause each square to have the color of the **previous** cell. So it's not that your first `Pixel` is located in the second square, it's that the second `Pixel` is drawing itself based on the color of the first `Pixel`. The same is true for the first `Pixel` drawing itself based on the color of the last `Pixel`.

To fix your problem, just set the stroke and fill **before** you call the `rect()` function.

Side note: you also probably want to get into the habit of using `{ }` curly brackets for every `if` statement, even one-liners like this:

```
if(this.one){
   fill(255);
}
```

This isn't causing any problems in your code yet, but it's a good habit to get into.